# Авторизация вконтакте

Tags: javascript

Делаю авторизацию через вконтакте oauth на php.
Открываю окно window.open, там подтверждаю или отклоняю доступ к данным. Скажите, как сделать, чтобы при разрешении закрывалось новое окно, и перенаправление уже шло в текущем окне, а при отклонении новое окно закрывалось?

Comment: Покажите код.

Comment: пока просто window.open("http://oauth.vk.com...

Comment: В текущем окне динамически создавайте "псевдоокно" при помощи тегов <div> ... <div/> и далее "играйтесь" переменными, которые у Вас отвечают за авторизацию. Вам помогут JS или JQuery.

Забыл еще подсказать: используйте Cookies, пример тут http://php.su/phphttp/?cookies

Comment: т.е. фрейм в модальном окне?

Comment: Забыл еще подсказать: используйте Cookies, пример тут http://php.su/phphttp/?cookies

Comment: никак, именно работать в новом окне и есть идеология apiVK

Comment: Тогда необходимо изучать интерфейс программирования приложений (API). P.S. Всем удачи, Евро 2012 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать [Open API](https://vk.com/dev/openapi)

> Open API - система для разработчиков сторонних сайтов, которая предоставляет возможность легко авторизовывать пользователей ВКонтакте на Вашем сайте.